# How to reliably start and stop a long running process (think days) that outlives the script that sarted it?

Tags: php

I have a CLI php app with a command that starts a background process (a Selenium server) and then exits:

> php app.php server:start #this should return immediatly

The app also needs to be able to stop the background process in a later invocation:

> php app.php server:stop

Since the server process outlives the start/stop script, I cannot manage it by keeping a file descriptor to it open.

I could store the PID of the process on the file system during `start` and kill that PID in `stop`. But if the `stop` command is ran after the background process has died of its own, I risk killing a process that I did not start because the PID might have been reused by the OS for some other process.

Right now my approach is to store not just the PID of the background process, but also the background process' start time and command used. It's OK, but it is hard to make it work consistently across different platforms (I need Linux, Mac, and Windows).

Can you think of a better way to implement such a behaviour?

Comment: You are looking for a "job scheduler".

Comment: i would create two scripts/cron jobs (start.sh & stop.sh) and schedule to run start.sh before stop.sh . you can set specific date/time